# Books sales volume data

Tags: book, sales

I am looking for a database / list of books with sales volume numbers for each title.  If this isn't available, then what is the best proxy for sales volume numbers that is available?  I am not just looking for the 'top 100' or 'bestsellers' books, I am looking for a database with as long a list of titles as is available.  The ideal data, were it available, would be something like a table / database or every title available on Amazon, with the corresponding sales volume (by year if possible).  I have been Googling, but not finding this.  Does this exist?  Is there a reasonable proxy?  The data do not have to be free.  If it is not free, then the data needs to be priced in such a way that it would be feasible to get a large list without it becoming cost-prohibitive (ie the whole list is for sale, or there is a substantial volume discount, rather than a focus on charging title by title).

Thank you for your help

Comment: I know there is a tool that you can use on Amazon to get the rankings for the different categories and subcategories. I don't remember if it includes sales and I will have to look up the name of the tool, since I don't remember that either. I do want to point out that the database for all of Amazon is beyond massive. What are you trying to get, as your end result? It may make a lot more sense to narrow the scope first.

Comment: The tool I was thinking of is called KDSpy. It's available at http://www.kdspy.com. I haven't used it but saw it used in a course on publishing with Kindle. It will give you information on the best sellers in different categories. Take a peek and see if it meets your needs.